# How can I determine what type a variable is?

Tags: c

My thinking is to use somehow the `if` operator lots of times and check for every type:

```
if (the variable has type int){
      return 0;
}
if (the variable has type double){
      return 1;
} 
...
```

Comment: A variable has a fixed, known type.  There is no need for conditional behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the type of a variable in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156226/getting-the-type-of-a-variable-in-c-code)

Comment: If you need to refer to an expression as a type -- you may look at `typeof` utilized by glibc.

Comment: `typeof` is an extension provided by GCC.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Your question has no much meaning in C11 (read *carefully* [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for details): the type of a given variable (or value) is known at *compile* time and *forgotten at runtime*, because you *declare* that (global, static, or automatic) variable with some explicit type. Be also aware that [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s define how data of different types might be handled differently (e.g. passed in various and *different* [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) or on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

Likewise, a function has a fixed and well-defined signature (you should give it when *declaring* the function, e.g. in some header file).

If you pass the *address* of some data as a `void*` formal argument (or some data as variadic argument), you need some *convention* to get its type (often, you'll pass another formal argument describing the type; [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is a typical example). For variadic functions, consider [`stdarg.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)  facilities.

Maybe you want to consider [generic selection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) with `_Generic` used in a macro. This is a feature that I very rarely use.

Maybe you want to customize your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler thru some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). That could take months of work (and is dependent of your particular version of GCC).

Maybe you want some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) or sum type. You'll typically implement that [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) with a `struct` containing an enumerator (choosing the type) and a `union`. For inspiration look into [Glib's GVariant](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html), and, since Glib is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), study its source code.

Perhaps you might want to look into [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

If you (specifically) use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), consider some of its [C language extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) (outside of the C11 standard). You might want [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) or some [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) like `__builtin_types_compatible_p`.

At last, you might *generate* some C file, perhaps using your script, another preprocessor like GPP or m4, etc...

You should describe your actual problem in details. In its initial form, your question is typically some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Although not clear from the OP's question, most people who ask me that are usually trying to have a function that accepts `void*` and then want to switch on the original type. Which is not great design, even if it was possible.